# Firebase Auth NodeJS: How to sign in through client instead of server?

Tags: node.js, firebase, heroku, socket.io, firebase-authentication

I have setup my firebase authentication on the server.js file and have used socket.io to transfer data and trigger change when user signs in and signs out. However, I was wondering how I can login through the client and not the server?

The reason is because when I login through the server, there is only one user that can be authenticated (Only one user to login at a time). Hence, if I login through client, many users can login.

Thanks.

Comment: Nearly all of the documentation about Firebase Authentication is about signing in directly from the client app.  Is there something specific about the documentation you're having problems with?  Have you tried something that doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Well, I setup firebase on my server.js because I have environmental variables and didn't want to expose them to the user. Would it be safe to run the 'onAuthStateChanged' if I moved all the setup variables from firebase initialisation to the client?

Comment: The client libraries are all designed to be safe to run from the client.  That's the default mode of operation.